# Does forecasting asset returns by default assumes non-stationarity of asset returns?

Tags: returns, forecasting, log-returns, stationarity

If we assume the assets returns are stationary then the best forecast can only be the mean of the distribution.

But if we assume non-stationarity we are forecasting the mean parameter (assuming normal distribution) using either linear or non-linear models. And to emphasize we are forecasting the mean rather than some exact value of the return distribution domain.

**Is my understanding correct?**

Answer (score 2):

This looks confused? I don't understand what you're saying in the second paragraph...

#### Comment 1: "Best" forecast depends on what you mean by "best."

Let $Y$ be a random variable and $\mathcal{F}$ be the information set. The "best" forecast depends on what the loss function is. If you're minimizing the expectation of squared loss:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x$)} & \mathbb{E}[(Y - x)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}] 
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

You have the solution that $x$ is the conditional expectation of $Y$ given information set $\mathcal{F}$
$$x^* = \mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{F}]$$

Of course you can have other loss functions. Consider minimizing the expected absolute error:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x$)} & \mathbb{E}[|Y - x| \mid \mathcal{F}] 
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
The solution here is that $x$ is the median of $Y$. Let $F^{-1}_Y$ be the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) for $Y$ conditional on information set $\mathcal{F}$.

$$ x^* = F_Y^{-1}(.5 \mid \mathcal{F})$$

#### Comment 2: The importance of stationarity

Let $\{ Y_t\}$ be a [stochastic process](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StochasticProcess.html). $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$ etc... are all random variables.

Speaking with imprecise language:

- Stationarity says that the unconditional distribution of $Y_1$ is the same as $Y_2$ is the same as $Y_3$ is the same as $Y_{1000}$ etc...
- Ergodicity says that process doesn't get stuck somewhere.

Stationarity says that you can talk about a time invariant expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. With ergodicity, a time-series mean $\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T Y_t$ will estimate that time invariant expectation (by an [ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Ergodic_theorems)). With stationarity and ergdocity, averages over time converge to averages over space.

With a non-stationary series, that's not true! Example. Let $\{X_t\}$ be a stochastic process.  Let $X_1$ be result of a die roll. Let $X_2$ be winning total of the Golden State Warriors vs. the LA Lakers. Let $X_3$ be the number of votes cast for BRexit. Let $X_4$ be the return on Apple stock December 10th. If I found a way to keep doing this, $X$ would be a non-stationary process. Talking about the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is non-sensical. There is no time-invariant expectation. And taking the average over time of $X$ does nothing useful at all.

(Note: Often times people have in mind a random walk when talking about a non-stationary process. In the case of a random walk, the first differences are stationary.)

Answer (score 1):

> If we assume the assets returns are stationary then the best forecast can only be the mean of the distribution.

This part is not accurate. [Stationarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process), even in its strongest sense, only implies that the unconditional distributions will be the same for every time index. Conditional distributions don't have to agree.

For instance, if the process $...,X_{-1},X_0,X_1,...$ is stationary, then  $E(X_{t+1}) = E(X_t)$. However, $E(X_{t+1})$ doesn't have to agree with $E(X_{t+1}|X_t)$.

Of course, asset returns turn out to be very difficult to forecast, but this doesn't follow from any assumption of stationarity alone.

Comment: I am guessing the statement you quote is only valid if we assume a very naive view of the returns coming from a univariate distribution (i.e. being unconditional). However most likely they are coming from a multidimensional distribution (where they are conditional on other values) making the statement inaccurate. Hence we forecast the mean either to take account for that conditionality or/and to take into account non-stationarity.

Comment: @a-l-verminburger Yes, if you in addition require the returns to be independent then that's correct.

Comment: Is independence not the same thing as stationarity? If it is stationary then at each subsequent moment in time I am sampling from the same distribution (with the same domain), e.g. tossing a coin. But if it is nonstationary (say a simple random walk) then the domain of the distribution I am sampling from depends on the realisation from the previous timestamp (i.e. is dependent on past a event) -- thinking of something like total earnings from tossing a coin.

Comment: @Winkelfried OK, so when you say "require the returns to be independent" you mean non-conditional. As I wrote in the first comment this is likely a naive view of returns and agree with you that would be the only scenario when the quoted statement would work. Non-stationarity is a little broader concept. It may encompass something like conditionality on previous distributions or it may be a parameters / domain of at current time being a function of just time (unrelated to previous distributions).

Comment: @a-l-verminburger Stationarity and independence are different notions. Neither of which implies the other. In a stationary process, the distribution (and also its domain) you sample from at a given time can depend on the previous timestamp. This is what I pointed out in the answer. A random walk is non-stationary but not because the distribution depends on the previous timestamp, but for other reasons, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246357/why-is-a-random-walk-not-a-stationary-process